# Bootstrap tabs resets animation?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, animation

I'm building a website using **bootstrap**, and in this website I'm using three bootstrap **tabs** just like these http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs. In my first tab I have an **animation** that clipps and image over time, starting from top to bottom. When I press another tab while the animation is running and then click back to the animation tab the animation as been **reseted**, it starts all over again even if it was not finished. I don't know why? And I don't want it to be like that.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Here is the animation code :)
 */

```
.powerups {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
}
.powerups img {
    position:absolute;
}
#p0 {
    -webkit-animation: Powertrimm 20s linear paused;
}
@-webkit-keyframes Powertrimm {
    from {clip:rect(0px,60px,60px,0px);}
    50% {clip:rect(30px,60px,60px,0px);}
    to {clip:rect(60px,60px,60px,0px);}
}
```

Comment: The screenshots are helpful, but it's pretty hard to diagnose a code issue without any code... please post the code you're using to set up the tabs, do the animations, anything that might affect the layout of your page, which version of Bootstrap, etc. Even better yet would be an additional working demonstration of the issue in a jsBin or jsFiddle.

Comment: I somehow want the animation to run in the backgorund when you tab. I think it mabey has something to do with bootstrap adds the class active to the showing tab. The code is also very long, so it would be to much to post the code.

Comment: You're probably right, but digging deeper you'll see that having the "active" class is what makes the current tab pane *visible*. My guess is that the class is controlling a `display: none` and `display: block` on those panes, and it's interfering with the animation.

Comment: I wonder if there's any way to workaround the problem :/

Comment: There very well could be, but we won't know until we see your code. It could be that you just have a mistake that's causing the behavior.

Comment: You should edit your question and add the code. You didn't mention that you're using CSS animations so I assumed jQuery animations. Unfortunately for you, the behavior you're seeing is exactly what I would expect. CSS doesn't remember the state of the elements it's affecting. Every time your elements are made visible by the tab pane being made visible, the animation executes.

Comment: I've now added the code. Would you rather recommend to mabey code the animation in javascript or jQuery? Do you belive that would solve my problem?

Comment: only in firefox right